# How can I get a number input value as a number instead of a string?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-input

Given a number input:

```
<input type="number" id="create-y-small" name="create-y-small" value="0">
```

How do I get the value of the input as a number? The following returns a string:

```
$("#create-y-small").val()
```

Why is this the default behavior? Surely one should expect a number type input to give a number?

I've looked for answers elsewhere but no luck:

[Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849944/input-value-is-a-string-instead-of-a-number) -
Answers use parsing to parse to a number. I don't want to parse to a number I just want to get the number as a number.

[Get variable value from input number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400049/get-variable-value-from-input-number) - OP seemed happy to get the value as a string

[Get the value of a input number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169407/get-the-value-of-a-input-number-in-jquery) - Same story

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+get+the+value+of+input+number+using+jquery - Same story

Comment: have you seen this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number ?

Comment: @ManishKumar I hadn't. Looks... messy. So best is to just parse?

Comment: yeah , we can parse or you can write a jQuery plugin for your app.

Comment: Side answer:  You have an `input` - it returns a string.  Your `input` has a `type` that determines *how the UI works*.  It's still an `input` so still returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `valHooks` to change how jQuery returns values.

```
$.valHooks.number = {
  get: function( elem ) {
    return elem.value * 1;
  }
};
```

You only need to do this once in your code and then all `type=number` inputs will instead return a number.

```js
console.log(
  "num is a string",
  $("#num").val() === "1", 
  $("#num").val() === 1, 
  $("#txt").val() === "1",
  $("#txt").val() === 1)

$.valHooks.number = {
  get: function( elem ) {
    return elem.value * 1;
  }
};

// confirm no neffect on type='text'
console.log(
  "num is a number",
  $("#num").val() === "1", 
  $("#num").val() === 1, 
  $("#txt").val() === "1",
  $("#txt").val() === 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='num' value="1">
<input type='text' id='txt' value="1">
```

Comment: Nice solution (I upvoted). However there's a caveeat: `"" * 1 = 0`. So one has to treat the missing value case (`""`) separately. Finally I think one can do: `value = parseFloat(elem.value); return isNaN(value) ? "" : value;`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent if you're using this solution then it's because you want a *number* - returning a `string` (`""`) would be a bad idea.

Comment: > I'm using number inputs in the cells of **datatables** table. The empty string is the only way I know to render a blank cell. What kind of problem could it cause?

Answer (score 2):

All input elements in HTML return a string as their value. If you want the result as an int, you have to convert it.

```
parseInt($("#create-y-small").val())
```